# Where do I update environment variables for git bash on Windows

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I'm setting up specific configuration combination consisting of Git + Gpg4Win + Powershell + Posh-git

All set up except git environment variables refer to git's version of ssh-agent so Posh-git is unable to auto start ssh-agent. (I need this so it doesn't ask me for ssh password during a shell session)

I found list of environment variables [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) but how do I change them? what file do I need to edit to update these?

Answer (score 0):

You can set them from the command line or

- right click the windows start button
- Click System
- Click Related Settings
- Click Advanced Settings
- Click Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for hours I managed to setup everything and even made a tutorial for other people in the future.

https://gist.github.com/metablaster/52b1baac5be44e2f1e6d16800813f42f